# Executing Powershell script that requires arguments from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, continuous-integration

I've got a project that looks like this:

```
project
|
├───src
│       Utility.groovy
│
└───vars
        pipeline.groovy
        script.ps1
```

In `pipeline.groovy` I have utility object:

```
def util = new Utility(this)
```

and a step that calls `util.scriptCall(arg1: "1", arg2: "2", arg3: "3")`, which is defined as:

```
this.context.powershell returnStdout: true, script: ".\\script.ps1 -Arg1 ${args.arg1} -Arg2 ${args.arg2} -Arg3 ${args.arg3} -Workspace ${this.context.env.workspace}"
```

From everything I've found I'm supposedly invoking this correctly, however I'm getting the following error:

```
.\script.ps1 : The term '.\script.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've got the Powershell plugin installed but the lack of documentation for anything related to Jenkins isn't helping. I've moved `script.ps1` into the `src` folder and even tried making a `scripts` folder for this with the same results.

Any idea why my invoking a script is getting interpreted as a cmdlet?

Comment: It means that it can't find that script in the "current directory" (`.`). Do you know what the current working directory is when you run that command? If not, maybe you can throw in a `pwd` or `ls` or something and try to see the output. Maybe the directory you're in is `project` and you'll need to call `./src/script.ps1` (PowerShell works fine with forward slashes `/` btw, in case you want to avoid having to escape backslashes all the time)

Comment: hey thanks for the `/` info! i was assuming that the workspace for jenkins would have been the `vars` directory but i'll mess around with the path and see if i can get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just a ding dong. The Workspace was the Git repo that was getting built. I had to relocate the script to that project and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Because the script is not available in the location, where you're trying to invoke the script.

Use the absolute path to invoke the script. If the path includes whitespaces  use the call operator (`&`).

```
& "absolutePathToScript/script.ps1"
```

I'm not hundred percent sure, but Jenkins will inject the workspace via `$env:workspace` (at least it will do so in normal PowerShell build steps), so you be able to invoke the script via:

```
& "$($env:workspace)/vars/script.ps1"
```

Comment: The Workspace was the git repository so I ended up having to just relocate the script. Thanks for the helpful info though!